# Set a particular email id for new activity

Tags: android, firebase, android-activity, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I want to set an if condition in an android studio. Please help me to implement this.
Logic like this

```
if (emailid = sanchyanchakraborty@gmail.com){
   Intent i = new Intent (this, Admiin.class);
}
else {
   Intent j = new Intent (this, Others,class);
}
```

// It means I want to specify only one email id which is already registered in firebase authentication database; if that email id entered, it will redirect an admin activity, else all other emaild id will be redirect in others activity.

Please help me out to implement this code.

Thanks

Comment: Is emailid the email you want? or you need to get from firebase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have already done the call to `Firebase` you simply do this :

```
Intent goToHome;
if(emailFromFirebase.equals("sanchyanchakraborty@gmail.com"){
   goToHome = new Intent(this,Admin.class);
else{
   goToHome = new Intent(this,Others.class);
}
startActivity(goToHome);
```

In one line could be :

```
startActivity(emailFromFirebase.equals("sanchyanchakraborty@gmail.com") ? new Intent(this,Admin.class) : new Intent(this,Other.class));
```